# Screen flickering on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: unity, compiz, 16.04

I have just updated (through Software Update) to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from 15.10. There are random instances of screen flickering throughout usage. After noticing this issue, I installed Compiz Config Settings Manager, selecting **Force fulls screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint**, which did nothing.

Is there any way this could be related to compiz settings or is this another issue?

---

EDIT: not fixed after clean install, upgrade to kernel 4.5.2, however screen flickering is reduced, it is every now and then (10 minutes apart). I will see if upgrading to kernel 4.6.0-994-generic will fix this.

---

EDIT: fixed as of kernel 4.6.2 generic,  currently running 4.7.2 without any issues.

Comment: kernel version is 4.4.0-21-generic

Comment: 3 gb ram, Radeon 1 GB graphics, kernel 4.4.0-36-generic. done the compiz thingy in my 16.04 lts. flickering doesn't stop.

Answer (score 3):

I suffered the similar problem today, when I upgraded a Lenovo V460 laptop to 16.04 from 15.10.

My case is due to bugs in kernel `4.4.0-21`, and switching to kernel `4.5.2` solves the issue. You can try a newer kernel from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), and follow the instruction [here](http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: This kernel (4.5.2) does not seem to fix the issue but the amount of screen flickering seems to be reduced, thank you. I will look into other kernels.

Comment: Doesn't fix it here either (dual graphics, Lenovo z-51-70, 4.5.2)

Comment: Lenovo T420s I had to install the `all` headers as the `amd64` headers failed on install.  I chose to install 4.5.5.

Comment: 4.5.3 didn't solve this issue for me. Still flickering on about every other scroll event.  :(