# Screen flickering 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, hybrid-graphics

After upgrading to 16.04 from 15.04, the screen presents full-screen flickers in varied colors. My specs are a ASUS N55SF with intel on-board graphics + Nvidia GeForce GT 555M. The flickering often happens when watching youtube and when running some scripts (python & C++).

I tried all solutions presented in both:
[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)
and
[Screen flickering on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760319/screen-flickering-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

I tried multiple nvidia drivers (from 304 to 370), running only with the intel graphic card (through prime-select). I also updated the kernel to 4.7 and 4.8.2 (currently), but nothing seems to work.

I believe that this is not a duplicate of the above questions because:
- the flickering also happens on tty when running some scripts
- also happens when I tried to reinstall ubuntu (during the installation process)

These two information make me think that is a hardware-related issue.